# Trying to complete a kata on codewars and my code passes all the given tests except the random test where it messes up my result?

Tags: javascript

https://www.codewars.com/kata/6375587af84854823ccd0e90/train/javascript
this is the kata..

this is my solution.. sorry for the format and the size but it works, or should, and i dont know why?

```
`function blockPrint(input){
  if (input.trim()=="") return"";
const string=input.trim().toUpperCase();    //trims off spaces and converts to uppercase
const map=[];
let output="";            // Uses the exact requirements given in expected output as shown below 
let pos=0;
map[0]=" AAA  BBBB   CCC  DDDD  EEEEE FFFFF  GGG  H   H IIIII JJJJJ K   K L     M   M N   N  OOO  PPPP   QQQ  RRRR   SSS  TTTTT U   U V   V W   W X   X Y   Y ZZZZZ";
map[1]="A   A B   B C   C D   D E     F     G   G H   H   I       J K  K  L     MM MM NN  N O   O P   P Q   Q R   R S   S   T   U   U V   V W   W X   X Y   Y     Z";
map[2]="A   A B   B C     D   D E     F     G     H   H   I       J K K   L     M M M N   N O   O P   P Q   Q R   R S       T   U   U V   V W   W  X X   Y Y     Z ";  
map[3]="AAAAA BBBB  C     D   D EEEEE FFFFF G GGG HHHHH   I       J KK    L     M   M N N N O   O PPPP  Q   Q RRRR   SSS    T   U   U V   V W W W   X     Y     Z  ";
map[4]="A   A B   B C     D   D E     F     G   G H   H   I       J K K   L     M   M N   N O   O P     Q Q Q R R       S   T   U   U V   V W W W  X X    Y    Z   ";  
map[5]="A   A B   B C   C D   D E     F     G   G H   H   I       J K  K  L     M   M N  NN O   O P     Q  QQ R  R  S   S   T   U   U  V V  W W W X   X   Y   Z    ";  
map[6]="A   A BBBB   CCC  DDDD  EEEEE F      GGG  H   H IIIII JJJJ  K   K LLLLL M   M N   N  OOO  P      QQQQ R   R  SSS    T    UUU    V    W W  X   X   Y   ZZZZZ";

 


  
  for (let i=0;i<7;i++){
  for(let j=0;j<string.length-1;j++){
    pos=(string.charCodeAt(j)-65)*6;    // works out which bit to add     
    if (pos=>0 && pos<=91){                        // and if its not a space
     output+=(map[i].slice(pos,pos+6)); // adds it
      }                                      //just do up till the last char because of test requirement for no trailing spaces
    
    if((pos/6)+65<65) {                // or if it is a space
        output+="      ";                // adds a space of 6 "spaces"
      }
            
  }
    pos=(string.charCodeAt((string.length)-1)-65)*6;        // finds the last char
    output+=(map[i].slice(pos,pos+6)).trimEnd();        // adds the bit with its "end" trimmed off as per the test requirements
    
 if(i<6) {output+="\n";}   //this to ensure no added carriage returns are added at the end as per test requirements 
  
} 
  
  
 console.log(output); 
  return output;
  
}`
```

I tried the above code, which passes all the given tests but for some weird reason, when its given "30 random chars" (which is anything up to 30) it either looks like it should pass (console log shows a match to expected output) or somehow it messes up the result by removing white spaces from the result or adding loads of random characters?? it seems to build up errors the more times I "attempt" it, I asked what was goin on and someone marked my question as "containing spoiler"??
Im guessing then, for that reason. I'm missing something fundamental about how javascript handles the data, or the way codewars tests work?

Comment: No space is inserted after Z, example blockPrint("zebra");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your output versus the same output through a diff tool, there appears to be a problem with the letter 'Z'.

Looking a little closer, it seems like every character in the string has a column of spaces after it, except the Z.

Comment: omg thankyou... its always soemething bloody silly, I had originally discounted that because of an earlier error many thanks that was driving me nuts

Comment: wont let me upvote but I did try a couple of times, apparently im not good enough yet ;)